# Is there a way to unescape code then see it?

Tags: javascript, html

One day I wanted to obfuscate my code for a Javascript login since I did not want people to find the passwords easier, but now I forgot which passwords were which, and I am having lots of troubles trying to change the password or see the content.

I have already tried "deobfuscators" but none worked unless you used their own system. I also tried making a bookmarklet, But I got the same code response.

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write(unescape('%3C%21%44%4F%43%54%59%50%45%20%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%20%20%3C%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%27%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%77%77%77%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%72%65%63%61%70%74%63%68%61%2F%61%70%69%2E%6A%73%27%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%69%63%6F%6E%22%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%76%67%79%2E%6D%65%2F%66%4C%73%54%47%66%2E%70%6E%67%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%62%6F%64%79%20%6F%6E%6C%6F%61%64%3D%22%63%68%65%63%6B%43%6F%6F%6B%69%65%28%29%22%3E%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%63%68%61%72%73%65%74%3D%22%75%74%66%2D%38%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%76%69%65%77%70%6F%72%74%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%77%69%64%74%68%3D%64%65%76%69%63%65%2D%77%69%64%74%68%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%74%69%74%6C%65%3E%4B%6F%6E%65%6B%6F%27%73%20%4C%6F%67%69%6E%3C%2F%74%69%74%6C%65%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%69%63%6F%6E%22%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%76%67%79%2E%6D%65%2F%66%4C%73%54%47%66%2E%70%6E%67%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%73%74%79%6C%65%2E%63%73%73%22%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%73%74%79%6C%65%73%68%65%65%74%22%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%63%73%73%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%2E%63%73%73%22%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%73%74%79%6C%65%73%68%65%65%74%22%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%63%73%73%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2F%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%3C%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%32%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%63%68%61%72%73%65%74%3D%22%55%54%46%2D%38%22%3E%0A%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%63%61%74%65%72%67%6F%72%79%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%53%63%68%6F%6F%6C%2C%43%6C%61%73%73%2C%45%64%75%63%61%74%69%6F%6E%22%3E%0A%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%6B%65%79%77%6F%72%64%73%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%41%6D%61%7A%69%6E%67%50%75%72%70%6C%65%7A%2C%43%61%74%73%2C%43%61%74%73%4E%44%65%61%6C%73%2C%43%61%74%73%44%65%61%6C%73%2C%4D%65%6E%75%2C%53%63%68%6F%6F%6C%2C%53%69%67%6E%49%6E%2C%4F%63%74%61%76%69%61%6E%2C%46%72%65%65%2C%57%65%62%2C%52%65%73%6F%75%72%63%65%73%2C%4B%69%74%2C%43%61%74%2C%4C%6F%67%69%6E%2C%49%64%65%6E%74%69%66%69%65%72%2C%43%61%74%73%4E%64%65%61%6C%73%20%49%64%65%6E%74%69%66%69%65%72%2C%20%43%61%74%6E%44%65%61%6C%73%20%53%69%67%6E%20%49%6E%2C%20%4B%6F%6E%65%6B%6F%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%0A%0A%3C%2F%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%0A%3C%62%6F%64%79%20%6F%6E%63%6F%6E%74%65%78%74%6D%65%6E%75%3D%22%72%65%74%75%72%6E%20%66%61%6C%73%65%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%62%6F%64%79%22%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%67%72%61%64%22%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%68%65%61%64%65%72%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%69%64%20%3D%20%22%6B%6F%6E%22%3E%4B%6F%6E%3C%73%70%61%6E%20%69%64%20%3D%20%22%6B%6F%6E%65%6B%6F%22%3E%65%6B%6F%3C%2F%73%70%61%6E%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%62%72%3E%0A%09%09%3C%66%6F%72%6D%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%3E%0A%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%69%6E%70%75%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%22%20%70%6C%61%63%65%68%6F%6C%64%65%72%3D%22%55%73%65%72%6E%61%6D%65%22%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%75%73%65%72%69%64%22%3E%3C%62%72%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%69%6E%70%75%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%20%69%64%20%3D%22%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%70%6C%61%63%65%68%6F%6C%64%65%72%3D%22%50%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%70%73%77%72%64%22%20%6B%65%79%2D%70%72%65%73%73%2D%65%6E%74%65%72%3D%22%63%68%65%63%6B%28%74%68%69%73%2E%66%6F%72%6D%29%22%3E%3C%62%72%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%70%3E%3C%70%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%67%2D%72%65%63%61%70%74%63%68%61%22%20%64%61%74%61%2D%73%69%74%65%6B%65%79%3D%22%36%4C%64%59%70%6F%55%55%41%41%41%41%41%4F%67%45%45%5F%52%6D%35%55%67%7A%5F%35%59%70%45%6A%54%36%44%79%76%5F%4A%30%66%53%22%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%69%6E%70%75%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%62%75%74%74%6F%6E%22%20%69%64%20%3D%20%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%20%6F%6E%63%6C%69%63%6B%3D%22%63%68%65%63%6B%28%74%68%69%73%2E%66%6F%72%6D%29%22%20%76%61%6C%75%65%3D%22%4C%6F%67%69%6E%22%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%09%09%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%3C%2F%66%6F%72%6D%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%73%63%72%69%70%74%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%2F%2F%20%74%72%79%69%6E%20%74%6F%20%66%69%6E%64%20%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%20%68%75%68%3F%0A%76%61%72%20%69%6E%70%75%74%20%3D%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%67%65%74%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%42%79%49%64%28%22%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%4F%6A%61%73%20%73%74%6F%70%20%74%68%69%6E%6B%69%6E%67%20%49%20%63%6F%70%79%20%63%6F%64%65%0A%69%6E%70%75%74%2E%61%64%64%45%76%65%6E%74%4C%69%73%74%65%6E%65%72%28%22%6B%65%79%75%70%22%2C%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%65%76%65%6E%74%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%59%6F%75%72%20%62%61%64%0A%20%20%65%76%65%6E%74%2E%70%72%65%76%65%6E%74%44%65%66%61%75%6C%74%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%79%6F%75%20%64%6F%20%6E%6F%74%20%68%65%6C%70%20%6D%65%0A%20%20%69%66%20%28%65%76%65%6E%74%2E%6B%65%79%43%6F%64%65%20%3D%3D%3D%20%31%33%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%75%72%20%62%61%64%20%61%74%20%77%61%72%66%72%61%6D%65%0A%20%20%20%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%67%65%74%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%42%79%49%64%28%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%29%2E%63%6C%69%63%6B%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%74%70%6F%73%65%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%0A%3C%70%3E%3C%2F%70%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%21%44%4F%43%54%59%50%45%20%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%3C%73%74%79%6C%65%3E'));
</script>
```

That is the full unescape, basically I thought that I could print the result using a javascript bookmarklet, but it just rewritten the random numbers and percent part. If anyone knows how to deobfuscate that would be amazing! THANK YOU ALL!

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `document.write` so you'll see the resulting HTML rather than rendering it.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try and get back if it works!

Comment: Thank you so much again, It worked and now I got my code.

Comment: Also thanks for not just -rep right away and actually helping.

Comment: Side note: Note the relative ease with which people helped you decode this, and ditch the idea of using client-side passwords in this manner. As you can see, it doesn't work. :-p

Comment: yeah I was 12 when I made this tbh.. I was early into coding and I forgot what it was. its something on repl.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly - just `document.write` it:

```js
document.write(unescape('%3C%21%44%4F%43%54%59%50%45%20%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%20%20%3C%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%27%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%77%77%77%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%72%65%63%61%70%74%63%68%61%2F%61%70%69%2E%6A%73%27%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%69%63%6F%6E%22%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%76%67%79%2E%6D%65%2F%66%4C%73%54%47%66%2E%70%6E%67%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%62%6F%64%79%20%6F%6E%6C%6F%61%64%3D%22%63%68%65%63%6B%43%6F%6F%6B%69%65%28%29%22%3E%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%63%68%61%72%73%65%74%3D%22%75%74%66%2D%38%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%76%69%65%77%70%6F%72%74%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%77%69%64%74%68%3D%64%65%76%69%63%65%2D%77%69%64%74%68%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%74%69%74%6C%65%3E%4B%6F%6E%65%6B%6F%27%73%20%4C%6F%67%69%6E%3C%2F%74%69%74%6C%65%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%69%63%6F%6E%22%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%76%67%79%2E%6D%65%2F%66%4C%73%54%47%66%2E%70%6E%67%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%73%74%79%6C%65%2E%63%73%73%22%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%73%74%79%6C%65%73%68%65%65%74%22%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%63%73%73%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6C%69%6E%6B%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%2E%63%73%73%22%20%72%65%6C%3D%22%73%74%79%6C%65%73%68%65%65%74%22%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%63%73%73%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2F%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%3C%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%32%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%63%68%61%72%73%65%74%3D%22%55%54%46%2D%38%22%3E%0A%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%63%61%74%65%72%67%6F%72%79%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%53%63%68%6F%6F%6C%2C%43%6C%61%73%73%2C%45%64%75%63%61%74%69%6F%6E%22%3E%0A%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%6B%65%79%77%6F%72%64%73%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%41%6D%61%7A%69%6E%67%50%75%72%70%6C%65%7A%2C%43%61%74%73%2C%43%61%74%73%4E%44%65%61%6C%73%2C%43%61%74%73%44%65%61%6C%73%2C%4D%65%6E%75%2C%53%63%68%6F%6F%6C%2C%53%69%67%6E%49%6E%2C%4F%63%74%61%76%69%61%6E%2C%46%72%65%65%2C%57%65%62%2C%52%65%73%6F%75%72%63%65%73%2C%4B%69%74%2C%43%61%74%2C%4C%6F%67%69%6E%2C%49%64%65%6E%74%69%66%69%65%72%2C%43%61%74%73%4E%64%65%61%6C%73%20%49%64%65%6E%74%69%66%69%65%72%2C%20%43%61%74%6E%44%65%61%6C%73%20%53%69%67%6E%20%49%6E%2C%20%4B%6F%6E%65%6B%6F%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%0A%0A%3C%2F%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%0A%3C%62%6F%64%79%20%6F%6E%63%6F%6E%74%65%78%74%6D%65%6E%75%3D%22%72%65%74%75%72%6E%20%66%61%6C%73%65%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%62%6F%64%79%22%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%67%72%61%64%22%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%68%65%61%64%65%72%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%69%64%20%3D%20%22%6B%6F%6E%22%3E%4B%6F%6E%3C%73%70%61%6E%20%69%64%20%3D%20%22%6B%6F%6E%65%6B%6F%22%3E%65%6B%6F%3C%2F%73%70%61%6E%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%3C%62%72%3E%0A%09%09%3C%66%6F%72%6D%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%3E%0A%09%09%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%69%6E%70%75%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%22%20%70%6C%61%63%65%68%6F%6C%64%65%72%3D%22%55%73%65%72%6E%61%6D%65%22%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%75%73%65%72%69%64%22%3E%3C%62%72%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%69%6E%70%75%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%20%69%64%20%3D%22%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%70%6C%61%63%65%68%6F%6C%64%65%72%3D%22%50%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%70%73%77%72%64%22%20%6B%65%79%2D%70%72%65%73%73%2D%65%6E%74%65%72%3D%22%63%68%65%63%6B%28%74%68%69%73%2E%66%6F%72%6D%29%22%3E%3C%62%72%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%70%3E%3C%70%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%67%2D%72%65%63%61%70%74%63%68%61%22%20%64%61%74%61%2D%73%69%74%65%6B%65%79%3D%22%36%4C%64%59%70%6F%55%55%41%41%41%41%41%4F%67%45%45%5F%52%6D%35%55%67%7A%5F%35%59%70%45%6A%54%36%44%79%76%5F%4A%30%66%53%22%3E%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%09%09%09%09%3C%69%6E%70%75%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%62%75%74%74%6F%6E%22%20%69%64%20%3D%20%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%20%6F%6E%63%6C%69%63%6B%3D%22%63%68%65%63%6B%28%74%68%69%73%2E%66%6F%72%6D%29%22%20%76%61%6C%75%65%3D%22%4C%6F%67%69%6E%22%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%09%09%3C%2F%64%69%76%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%3C%2F%66%6F%72%6D%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%73%63%72%69%70%74%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%2F%2F%20%74%72%79%69%6E%20%74%6F%20%66%69%6E%64%20%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%20%68%75%68%3F%0A%76%61%72%20%69%6E%70%75%74%20%3D%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%67%65%74%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%42%79%49%64%28%22%70%61%73%73%77%6F%72%64%22%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%4F%6A%61%73%20%73%74%6F%70%20%74%68%69%6E%6B%69%6E%67%20%49%20%63%6F%70%79%20%63%6F%64%65%0A%69%6E%70%75%74%2E%61%64%64%45%76%65%6E%74%4C%69%73%74%65%6E%65%72%28%22%6B%65%79%75%70%22%2C%20%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%28%65%76%65%6E%74%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%59%6F%75%72%20%62%61%64%0A%20%20%65%76%65%6E%74%2E%70%72%65%76%65%6E%74%44%65%66%61%75%6C%74%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%79%6F%75%20%64%6F%20%6E%6F%74%20%68%65%6C%70%20%6D%65%0A%20%20%69%66%20%28%65%76%65%6E%74%2E%6B%65%79%43%6F%64%65%20%3D%3D%3D%20%31%33%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%75%72%20%62%61%64%20%61%74%20%77%61%72%66%72%61%6D%65%0A%20%20%20%20%64%6F%63%75%6D%65%6E%74%2E%67%65%74%45%6C%65%6D%65%6E%74%42%79%49%64%28%22%6C%6F%67%69%6E%22%29%2E%63%6C%69%63%6B%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%74%70%6F%73%65%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%0A%3C%70%3E%3C%2F%70%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%21%44%4F%43%54%59%50%45%20%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%3C%73%74%79%6C%65%3E'));
```

Note: it has some errors because the code is running on a different site (`stacksnippets.net`) than it should (your website)

Comment: yeah, I know but that website is down.. the code was terrible and it was my early stages of coding in javascript, I am not really good at javascript so now I usually do stuff in php but thanks for answering, its an old code from long ago. I just did not know how to make it print to console.